# Как организовать выборку элементов в HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

В переменной `tr` 4 вхождения. В цикле `foreach` я пробегаюсь по этому списку и каждый раз в переменной `item` новые данные, однако `item.SelectSingleNode` всегда возвращает одно и тоже значение. Что я делаю не так?  Есть конечно вариант занести все вхождения сразу в список - список `фирм` отдельно, список `артикулов` отдельно и потом их в общий список, но может быть и так, что артикулов может быть больше чем фирм.

```
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='ResTab sortable']");
    var tr = nodes.SelectNodes("//tr[contains(@id,'ctl00_mainPlace_SearchRepeater')]");

    foreach (var item in tr)
             {
               var articul =item.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='NumberTH']").InnerHtml;
               var firm =tr.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='FirmTH']").InnerHtml);
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `var firm = --> tr <-- .SelectSingleNode`?

Comment: не совсем понятно на чтл вы намекаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var trs = d.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
               "//table[@class='ResTab sortable']" + 
               "//tr[starts-with(@id, 'ctl00_mainPlace_SearchRepeater')]");
foreach (var tr in trs) {
   var articul = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[@class='NumberTH']").LastChild.InnerText.Trim();
   var firm = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[@class='FirmTH']").InnerText.Trim();
   Console.WriteLine(firm + " " + articul);
}
```

Comment: в принципе ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Radzhab попробуйте вместо `/tr` указать `//tr`. если не сработает, то дайте html или url, чтобы я проверил почему не работает.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/L0UiJNn5

Comment: //tr не помогло

Comment: выдернул только div, надеюсь hap сможет его прочитать

Comment: @Radzhab _"выдернул только div, надеюсь hap сможет его прочитать"_ -- проверил. вместо `contains` надо `starts-with`. обновил ответ.